# Google Sign In & Firebase with SwiftUI

Tags: ios, firebase, swiftui, firebase-authentication, google-oauth

Hi all I was trying to use sign in with **google** and **firebase** in a `SwiftUI`  project. Now checking the old implementation methods and also some suggestions got from the net I am having problem with this part of the code

```
private func authenticateUser(for user: GIDGoogleUser?, with error: Error?) {
  // 1
  if let error = error {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
    return
  }
  
  // 2
  guard let authentication = user?.authentication, let idToken = authentication.idToken else { return }
  
  let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: idToken, accessToken: authentication.accessToken)
  
  // 3
  Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { [unowned self] (_, error) in
    if let error = error {
      print(error.localizedDescription)
    } else {
      self.state = .signedIn
    }
  }
}
```

I'm getting errors with this `authentication` constant

```
  guard let authentication = user?.authentication, let idToken = authentication.idToken else { return }
```

The error is `Value of type 'GIDGoogleUser' has no member 'autentication'`

---

i know google dropped some properties replacing them...currently how can i update the google login implementation in SwiftUI?

Comment: Your code says `authentication`, but the error says `autentication` -- are you trying to access it somewhere with the misspelling in the latter one?

Comment: @jnpdx No even if I correct the spelling it keeps giving me the same error

Comment: Which version of the Google Sign In SDK are you using? There's been a major release a while ago (7.0.0 is current as of this writing). If you look at the header file (https://github.com/google/GoogleSignIn-iOS/blob/main/GoogleSignIn/Sources/Public/GoogleSignIn/GIDGoogleUser.h#L42), you will see that `GIDUser` objects have an `idToken` and an `accessToken` property.  Coincidentally, I am working on a Firebase Fundamentals video about Google Sign-In in SwiftUI, should be released with the next couple of days.

Comment: @PeterFriese in fact `GIDGoogleUser `  contains only `accessToken`  and `idToken`  not `authentication`

Answer (score 4):

Here is how you can authenticate a Firebase user when using Google Sign-In using the latest release (7.0.0) of the [Google Sign-In SDK](https://github.com/google/GoogleSignIn-iOS):

```swift
extension AuthenticationViewModel {
  func signInWithGoogle() async -> Bool {
    guard let clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID else {
      fatalError("No client ID found in Firebase configuration")
    }
    let config = GIDConfiguration(clientID: clientID)
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.configuration = config

    guard let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene,
          let window = windowScene.windows.first,
          let rootViewController = window.rootViewController else {
      print("There is no root view controller!")
      return false
    }

      do {
        let userAuthentication = try await GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn(withPresenting: rootViewController)

        let user = userAuthentication.user
        guard let idToken = user.idToken else { throw AuthenticationError.tokenError(message: "ID token missing") }
        let accessToken = user.accessToken

        let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: idToken.tokenString,
                                                       accessToken: accessToken.tokenString)

        let result = try await Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential)
        let firebaseUser = result.user
        print("User \(firebaseUser.uid) signed in with email \(firebaseUser.email ?? "unknown")")
        return true
      }
      catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        self.errorMessage = error.localizedDescription
        return false
      }
  }
}
```

Check out [Getting started with Google Sign-In on Apple platforms - YouTube](https://youtu.be/IzyOdKm0bWE), in which I explain the configuration options in more detail.

Comment: What I fail to understand is why Firebase doesn't update the documentation based on updates

Comment: Fair point. I will make sure to fix this. One of the reasons is that Google Sign-In and Firebase are separate teams, and it’s not always easy to keep things in sync. That’s not an excuse - I just wanted to explain why these things happen.

Comment: Perfect thank you .. looking forward to your video on Google Sign In.. Can you post the link here in this question when you have completed the video ?

Comment: hello peter! were you able to post the video you were talking about for implementing google sign in with firebase?

Comment: Hey @kAiN - yes, it just went live to a few hours ago: https://youtu.be/IzyOdKm0bWE, and an update for the docs is also in review and should go out this week.